# Error - Model not part of the Current Context

Tags: c#, sql-server, oop, console-application

I have this error which appeared recently and i don't know what i have wrong

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type Customer is
>   not part of the model for the current context.'

The Error is appearing in the List (Customer) when i run the code

The Model is connected to an SQL Database which has the Customer Table

NEED HELP PLS CAUSE I CANT CONTINUE WITH THE PROGRAM. THANKS

**Main Program**

```
static StoreSalesHandlingNewEntities1 db = new StoreSalesHandlingNewEntities1();

public static string ShowMenu()
{
    Console.Clear();
    List<Customer> customerList = db.Customer.ToList();
    foreach (Customer c in customerList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("1.. Login");
    Console.WriteLine("2.. Register");
    Console.WriteLine("3.. Exit");
    return Console.ReadLine();

}
```

**Context**

```
public partial class StoreSalesHandlingNewEntities1 : DbContext
{
    public StoreSalesHandlingNewEntities1()
        : base("name=StoreSalesHandlingNewEntities1 ")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
}
```

**Customer**

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public int MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0}, Surname: {1}, ID Number: {2}, Email: {3}, Address: {4}, Mobile: {5}, Username: {6}, Password: {7}",
            Name, Surname, IDNumber, EmailAddress, HomeAddress, MobileNumber, Username, Password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting everything in one class (`Customer`). Generally, good practice is using POCOs and class `Customer` isn't one. Basically, I see that you used DB-first approach. But then, you altered `Customer` class (at least). This might cause the problem.

Comment: Show me an example with code please cause i didn't understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are not created on startup, this is why. You need to tell the DbContext about them in the OnModelCreating method override.

You can either do custom per-entity mappings here, or separate them out into separate EntityTypeConfiguration classes.

Put this in your custom DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I still have the same error after adding the code you sent me